# Computing $2^{2^1}+2^{2^2}+2^{2^3}+\cdots+2^{2^n}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

How can I compute the following sum?
$$2^{2^1}+2^{2^2}+2^{2^3}+\cdots+2^{2^n}$$
My attempt was to apply the known formula for the sum of an geometric progression, but it seems that the ratio is variable. So there is a formula for this type of sum?

Comment: A natural way to start is to compute the sum for $n=1,2,3,\cdots$ and see if you can find any useful pattern.

Comment: If the first term is 2 then this is [OEIS sequence A060803](https://oeis.org/A060803) with almost no information about the sequence given in the entry. I think you are out of luck here.

Comment: What do you mean by "compute", here? You can compute all the terms by repeated squaring, and add them. A closed formula would not help you compute it much faster, because just outputting the digits already takes up a relatively large amount of the time.

Answer (score 5):

There is no known closed form for this series.

Anyway, as the terms grow extremely fast, even for moderate $n$,

$$\frac{t_{n-1}}{t_n}=2^{2^{n-1}-2^n}=2^{-2^{n-1}}$$ is a tiny ratio and

$$2^{2^1}+2^{2^2}+2^{2^3}+\ldots+2^{2^n} \approx 2^{2^n}.$$

E.g., for $n=6$, the ratio is $2.3\cdot10^{-10}$. In fact, when keeping only the final term, the value is exact on the first half of the digits.

---

$$2,4,16,256,65536,4294967296,18446744073709551616,340282366920938463463374607431768211456,\cdots$$
compared to
$$2,6,22,278,65814,4295033110,18446744078004584726,340282366920938463481821351509772796182,\cdots$$

Comment: "There is no closed form for this series." -- can you substantiate this claim?

Comment: @MeesdeVries: a little bird told me. I will change to "no known closed form".

Comment: I ask mostly because my intuition agrees, and I feel like for the right notion of "closed form" it might be provable. Something like: the sequence grows quickly enough yet with enough irregularity, similar to how Liouville numbers are shown to be transcendental. Edit: To be clear the comment was not a criticism of the answer. The upvote was mine.

Comment: I agree with Yves. I doubt there is any useful formula for this. Basically because the last term is such a good approximation. Also, I suspect that the "full series" (trivially converging in the 2-adic domain) has a sum that is transcendental over $\Bbb{Q}$, again suggesting (but not implying) no formula.

Comment: I mean, it sure looks like the sum of the series would be a $2$-adic [Liouville number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number).

Comment: @MeesdeVries: the trouble is that AFAIK there is no theory of closed-forms for the summations like there is one for the antiderivatives. Maybe Liouville's theorem can be rewritten for the discrete functions, who knows ? Another terrible challenge is about the closed-form of roots of transcendental functions.

Answer (score 2):

Allow me to suggest a paper that discusses what constitutes an answer to these kinds of problems (he focuses on counting problems, but the general idea can be generalized): Herbert S. Wilf, What is an Answer?, *The American Mathematical Monthly*, Vol. 89, No. 5 (May, 1982), pp. 289-292. The general idea applied to this particular problem would be whether there is a more efficient way to find the sum that just adding term by term.  Working in binary you could express the sum by a string of 0's and 1's in which all digits are zero except for a 1 in positions $2^1$, $2^2$, $2^4$, etc., but that already requires a number of operations at least as long as the number of terms in the sum, so it looks like we are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$\alpha_n = 2^{2^{n}},$$
 $$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \alpha_n.$$
Then
$$ \frac{\alpha_{n+1}}{\alpha_{n}} = \alpha_{n},$$
$$ \alpha_{n+1} = \alpha_{n}^2.$$
$$S_n^2 = (\sum_{k=1}^{n} \alpha_k)^2 =\sum_{k=1}^{n} \alpha_k^2 + 2 \sum_{i <j}^{n} \alpha_{i} \alpha_{j} =\sum_{k=1}^{n} \alpha_{k+1}+2 \sum_{i <j}^{n} \alpha_{i} \alpha_{j}.$$
Fixing the summation
$$S_n^2 = S_n +\alpha_{n+1}-\alpha_{1} +2 \sum_{i <j}^{n} \alpha_{i} \alpha_{j},$$
$$ S_n^2 -S_n +(\alpha_1-\alpha_{n+1}-2 \sum_{i <j}^{n} \alpha_{i} \alpha_{j})=0,  $$
$$ S_n = \frac{1+ \sqrt{8  \sum_{i <j}^{n} \alpha_{i} \alpha_{j}+4 \alpha_{n+1}+1-4\alpha_1}}{2}.$$
The problem is now to calculate 
$$\sum_{i <j}^{n} \alpha_{i} \alpha_{j}.$$